# What HTML Language Code should I use for Sranantongo?

Tags: html

I need to add support to my application for a new language.

My application shows HTML webpages in an internal `CHtmlView` browser control.

I have looked through the language codes [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_language_codes.asp) for:

- Sranantongo

But it is not listed. What language code should I use?

Comment: If in doubt you should not rely on third party pages but consult the official ISO documentation references themselves. Especially w3schools has a bad reputation for being well known despite having serious faults among the statements they make on their pages...

Comment: On further investigation this page uses `srn` https://www.jw.org/srn/ when you view the source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now stumbled over this [web page](https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php).

It appears more comprehensive.

It states:

[image: Language]

So it looks like the right code is `srn`.

Answer (score 0):

With one google search, i've found that `Sranantongo` is the speaking language of Suriname. Then i found on the page you gave the link :

```
SURINAME    SR
```

Comment: Thanks. I did notice this link https://www.loc.gov/standards/iso639-2/php/code_list.php which specifically mentions `srn`. Are we allowed to use these 3 letter codes? Or must I use `sr`?